# Release Management Online Tokenization not working

Tags: ms-release-management, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am following the tutorial here to tokenize my web.config settings.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/release/examples/azure/change-config-azure-webapps#tokenization

I have a web app deployed to Azure. But the web.config tokens are not being replaced. I have 2 tokens in my custom config section.

```
myBaseAddress = "_baseAddress_"
myEndpoint = "_endpointUrl_"
```

The release variables are defined in the release definition specified as

```
Name: baseAddress Value: abc.com
Name: endpointUrl Value: xyz.com
```

The release is successful but when I check the web.config on the server, the values are not replaced. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
myBaseAddress = "__baseAddress__"
myEndpoint = "__endpointUrl__"
```

You only have one "_" character in the token.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.